# crud repository find users by job

Tags: spring-boot

i want to find all users with the same job but i get an error : Parameter with that position [1] did not exist; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter with that position [1] did not exist

my repo :

```
public interface AppUsersRepo extends CrudRepository<AppUsers,Integer> {

    @Query("SELECT t FROM AppUsers t WHERE t.job = 'teacher'")
    public List<AppUsers> findAllByJob(String job);
}
```

my controller :

```
public class MainController {

    @Autowired
    AppUsersRepo appRepo;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public ModelAndView doHome() {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("index");
        mv.addObject("lists",appRepo.findAll());
        return mv;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/test")
    public ModelAndView recoverPass() {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("test");
        mv.addObject("lists",appRepo.findAllByJob());
        return mv;
    }
}
```